# Which files in bin/Release folder are needed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio

After building the release version for my application, I went to the bin/Release folder and saw a bunch of my project dependencies, such as "Newtonsoft.Json.dll", "System.Memory.dll" and so on.

I have referenced posts like [What files are mandatory in release windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419560/what-files-are-mandatory-in-release-windows-form) and saw that these dependencies are needed for my application to run smoothly.

However, I only needed to copy one file - my "main.dll" to the application (I'm creating an add-on for Revit) and it works fine. So, I'm wondering which files could be excluded? This is because my application is still being modified and new dependencies are being added, and I would like to know which files are not needed.

Is there a list of dependencies that have already been included in windows automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you *probably* need them all ***and*** *sometimes* some.  The long version -- it depends.  Below is not an exhaustive list but some points to consider:

- Whatever is part of the .NET framework that you are using is not ***normally*** copied to the output directory
- The examples that you listed ***normally*** should be copied to the output as they are ***not*** part of .NET Framework
- You can force a reference to be copied by setting `Copy Local` to `true`, which would result in a potentially unnecessary DLL in your output directory
- You may have some dependencies in the GAC, which means they might not be copied to the output directory. For example, are you using Infragistics, etc. controls -- do all of your users have them installed on their machines?  Probably not and they probably shouldn't, so include them...
- The compiler is generally smart about not including things to which you have no actual code references (this can lead to problems if there are dynamic invocations only)